# Character tables of $D_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have just obtained the character table of $D_4$, and now I want to know if all $D_n$ groups have similar character tables. Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

There are many references in the literature, e.g., the article [Characters of the dihedral group](http://math.webgirand.eu/pdf/dvp_agreg/Dn_en.pdf), and Serre's book on linear representations of finite groups.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the relation about your elements.
Let $ r $ be rotation and $ s$ be simetry.

$sr=r^{n-1}s$, $r^n=1$ and $s^2=1$.

That's produces similar tables.

Comment: This isn't sufficient reasoning. The parity of $n$ affects the character table.